# Decompile Classic Mac Binary

Tags: c, binary, reverse-engineering, decompiler

I have a binary file for a classic mac program that I would like to decompile to take a look at.  I have tried several 68000 decompilers and haven't had much luck.  These are the ones that I have tried:

http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/rec.htm

http://www.fourmilab.ch/xd/

Is there a better way to go about this or another program that works better?

My hope is to get a C source file, which is what I assume this program was written in.

Comment: How much luck do you need ? What do you mean specifically by 'not much luck' ?

Comment: I guess I worded that wrong.  So far these programs haven't worked for me.  I haven't gotten any useful output yet.

Comment: Back in the day we used MacNosy. Too bad that's not an option anymore.

Comment: "My hope is to get a C source file" -- you can flat out forget that. Best thing you can get is *a* disassembly, and there are no guarantees it's "correct" (the code/data dichotomy). If you are lucky, the code started out as C, in which case you can scan for a few recurrent code patterns. But the older the binary is, the larger chances are it was largely or even entirely hand-coded.